# Filter observableArray by condition

Tags: knockout.js

I want to be able to filter a list by a specific condition. I dont want to use any other observble arrays to store the filtered items in, i want to overwrite the current array.

HTML:

```
<div class='list'>
    <select data-bind="options: storedProceduresInDB1, value: filterStoredProceduresInDB1By, optionsText: 'Profile', optionsValue: 'Profile', optionsCaption: 'Filter by Profile'"></select>
    This will only filter the list below
    <p>Stored procedures:</p>
    <select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:storedProceduresInDB1, optionsText: 'Name', selectedOptions:selectedStoredProceduresInDb1"></select>
</div>
```

Code:

```
var SProcsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.storedProceduresInDB1 = ko.observableArray([{
        Name: "Sp1",
        Id: 1,
        Profile: 100
    }, {
        Name: "Sp2",
        Id: 2,
        Profile: 100
    }, {
        Name: "Sp3",
        Id: 3,
        Profile: 200
    }, {
        Name: "Sp4",
        Id: 4,
        Profile: 300
    }]);

    self.filterStoredProceduresInDB1By = ko.observable();
    self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1 = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb2 = ko.observableArray();

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new SProcsViewModel());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrqyR/2/)

EDIT: If i choose Profile 100 i want to overwrite storedProceduresInDB1 with all items that have profile 100. As you can see in [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/LrqyR/5/) i can't change data-bind to other Array.

Comment: And what happens after choosing Profile 100 and THEN, say, Profile 200?

Comment: I have an observableArray with the ordinary items, so i'll just overwrite with that values and then do the filtering again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing *exactly* what you're asking for by the way you've phrased your question, you can subscribe to the change events of `filterStoredProceduresInDB*By` and overwrite the arrays from there, like this:

```
var filterCallback = function ( array, newValue ) {
    array( ko.utils.arrayFilter( array(), function ( storedProcedure ) {
        return storedProcedure.Profile === newValue;
    } ) );
};

self.filterStoredProceduresInDB1By.subscribe( filterCallback.bind( self, self.storedProceduresInDB1 ) );
self.filterStoredProceduresInDB2By.subscribe( filterCallback.bind( self, self.storedProceduresInDB2 ) );
```

This will directly overwrite your observable arrays. However, as you can probably see if you test it out in [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrqyR/3/), it's not a very good idea, as you lose any data that doesn't pass your filter, so there's no way to change the filter afterwards without doing a lot of manual plumbing to fetch the original data and put it back into the array before filtering again.

This is one of the best and most common use cases for computed observables. Create a computed observable that returns a filtered projection of your array, instead of directly overwriting the array, as people have noted in the other answers/comments.

```
self.filteredStoredProceduresInDB1 = ko.computed( function () {
    var filterBy = self.filterStoredProceduresInDB1By();
    if ( !filterBy )
        return self.storedProceduresInDB1();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter( self.storedProceduresInDB1(), function ( storedProcedure ) {
        return storedProcedure.Profile === filterBy;
    } );
} );
```

Then bind the displayed list to the computed observable instead. [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LrqyR/4/)

Comment: Everything seems to work as intended in the fiddle you linked. What exactly doesn't work there? There's nothing about your functionality that conflicts with using an additional computed observable.

Comment: My mistake, i found the reason why its not worked. :) Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to distinct profile's in their select lists so same profiles only occur once ? thanks for your time.

Comment: Absolutely, you can do that using - you guessed it - another set of computed observables. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrqyR/7/

Answer (score 3):

You'll need computed observable (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Your question is not realy precise so I don't realy know what/how you want to filter. Here's the idea (psedo code):

```
this.filteredArray = ko.computed(function(){
     var filtered = [];
     for (yourvar) // loop on your original array
       if (filter)
         filtered.push(yourvar[i])
    return filtered;
}, this);
```

Adding this in your model will do the trick, you can then use `filteredArray` as a `var` in your `data-bind` :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filteredArray">
   $data
</div>
```

Comment: Nice way of avoiding storing the filtered data in another `observableArray`

Comment: That's pretty much why `computed` exists ^^

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont want to use Another Array in the databind.

Comment: It is a temporary array...it will be hard to avoid and keep a clean code. It might even be impossible, even if you use something like `$.map` there is an hidden array somewhere

Comment: Can you specify the reason why you don't want to use another array in the databind? There's no downside to this whatsoever...

Comment: @Hans ie. In the real application you can copy items from a list to another and then a lot of other functions that uses the storedProceduresInDB1 array.